# Why do the magnetic poles move?

Tags: geomagnetism, solar-terrestrial-physics, poles

Does the Earth position in the galaxy or solar system affect the orientation of the magnetic axis?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean? Are you asking if there is a correlation between the location of Earth's magnetic pole and the position of Earth (as part of the solar system) in the galaxy?

Comment: In addition to Michael's query, are you suggesting that Earth's axis of spin is related to the location of the magnetic poles?

Comment: @Fred yes that the hole iron core flips when the poles reverse and that is caused by something outside the Earth and possibly outside the solar system.

Comment: @Muze the iron core does not flip during a geomagnetic reversal. Also, geomagnetic reversal events are (almost) random and do not correlate with the position of the Earth in the galaxy or in the solar system.

Comment: I edited the question for re-opening, because I think there is a core a good question in there that I would like to know the answer to as well.

Comment: I think with the edit, the question is now clear, but the answer is (to the best of my knowledge) a hard no for the reasons that @Michael says.   The Earth's orbital position is a fair bit like clockwork.  Earth's magnetic flips are quite chaotic.  There could be a loose correlation, related to variations in Earth's orbital speed which vary somewhat with the rise and fall of ice ages, which are correlated to orbital cycles, but that's a bit of a guess on my part, and a loose relation not a neat one.

Comment: Voted for reopen, I think this could be fashioned into a valid question about the causes of true polar wander.